# Object.CategoryName into List<string> of category names

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<MyObject> listObjects` where I would like a unique list of `MyObject.CategoryName` as `List<string>`.

I have the following linq so far.

```
var categoryNames = from element in listObjects
orderby element.CategoryName
group element by element.CategoryName;
```

However, `var categoryNames` is a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyObject>>`.

How can I get the list as a `List<string>`?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var categoryNames = listObjects.Select(x => x.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList();
```

In words: "Grab only the category names, and then ignore duplicates, and put them into a list."

Answer (score 1):

```
var categoryNames = listObjects.Select(o=>o.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList()
```